# Mapping template for API gateway to firehose results in avoid invalid json

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using API Gateway to receive data from a webhook and pushing it to Kinesis. Using mapping template, I create a JSON using data from the webhook payload.
The problem is, when I encode it to base64 and Kinesis decodes it, it ends up becoming an invalid json. The ":" get replaced by "=".

Here's my mapping template:

```
#set ($account = $util.parseJson($input.params().header.get("some-field")).account) //fetching a field from a header

{
"StreamName": "$input.params('stream-name')",
"Data": "$util.base64Encode(
        {"Payload": "$input.json('$.payload')", 
        "Account": "$account", 
        "Event": "$input.json('$.event')"
        })",
"PartitionKey": "$account"
}
```

What's happening is, the `Data` JSON object is getting corrupted when it gets decoded by Firehose for inline parsing (for dynamic partitioning). I get

```
{
Payload={"a":1,"b":2},
Account=abcdehdds,
Event="abc"
}
```

Notice the `=` instead of `:`, making this an invalid JSON.

What's strange is when the data is pushed from Firehose to s3 without any dynamic partitioning, it's a perfect JSON.

I'm at my wits end trying to solve this. Would appreciate any help.